# Test results are published correctly but not reflected in pipeline Results - Azure devops (Yaml)

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, mstest, azure-search-.net-sdk

We are using Azure Devops 2019 and Yaml Pipeline in order to execute out GUI Testcases. The tests get executed on Microsoft runagent. Recently we have updated our Framework to Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk style and since then we have a strange problem as below.

**Problem** :- When we run the tests, tests are actualyy executed on run agent, in Logs one sees that Results were published successfully (done through TCM Test result publisher), But the Tests remain in status "In Progress" no matter whether it was actually passed or failed.

Also we noticed that the Tests which do not have any Data Source are executed rightly and their Result is also shown correctly. ([TestMethod, TestProperty("TestCaseId", "27089"), TestCategory("Smoke"), TestCategory("Selenium"), TestCategory("Appium")])

But unfortunately no Result is shown for the Tests that have Data source.
[TestMethod, TestProperty("TestCaseId", "27080"), TestCategory("Smoke"), TestCategory("Selenium")]
**[DataSource("TC27080")**]

Our Project has following Dependecies (after the update that we did):

[image]

Any idea what could go wrong with these new update. (We could confirm that reverting this commit solves the problem but we would like to know what is exactly wrong with the the update that we did)

Answer (score 0):

Following was the problem :- MSTest nuget Package version 2.2.4 onwards has this problem with Data driven Tests. https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/1023

We downgraded the MSTest package version to 2.2.3 and now the Test results are shown correctly.